# Nginx for request throttling. Render html page before proxy_pass to backend

Tags: nginx

Basically what I am trying to do is to create reverse proxy with request throttling. I have been able to configure request throttling, but there is one more thing that I would like to do.

```
upstream demo {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
    server 127.0.0.1:3001;
    server 127.0.0.1:3002;
    server 127.0.0.1:3003;
}

location / {
    root   html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    #limit_req zone=one burst=5;
    try_files index.html @demo;
}

location @demo {
    limit_req zone=one burst=5;
    root /home/ec2-user/demo/public/;
    proxy_pass http://demo;
}
```

I would like to:

1) Render a sample html page like "Wait, for security measures, you are going to be redirected to your application in X seconds"

2) After X seconds, pass the request to the upstream backend.

Is it possible to do with Nginx? I am using latest OpenResty distribution.

Thanks,